# Magento 1.9.3.3 - How do you return a JSON array from a controller to ajax

Tags: ajax, json, magento-1.9.3.3

I have a ajax call to a controller (suburbSearchAction) which retrieves a list of suburbs based suburb text received from the user

**Ajax call**

```
inputSuburbData = jQuery(inputSuburb).val().trim();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/service/Index/suburbsearch',
            data: {inputSuburbData:inputSuburbData},
            complete: function(responseData) {

                console.log(responseData);

            },
            error:function(response){

                console.log('Response Error');
                console.dir(response);
            }
        });
```

**Controller Code**

```
<?php

class Vendor_Service_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function suburbSearchAction()
    {

        /* Get Suburb text from POST Request */
        $suburbNameQuery = $this->getRequest()->getParam('inputSuburbData');

        /* Retrieve Service Model at: Vendor/Service/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ram.php */
        $model = Mage::getModel('vendor/shipping_carrier_ram');
        Mage::register('suburb_query', $suburbNameQuery);
        $model->_getSuburbs();
        $suburbResultArray = Mage::registry('suburb_resultset');

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($suburbResultArray));
    }
}
```

I can confirm the following:

- The ajax call calls the controller suburbSearchAction()
- The varibale in the controller $suburbResultArray has an array of suburbs. so everything is working up till here

My problem is i am unable get the response json to return back to the JavaScript file on completion of the ajax call. it simply returns nothing. The responseData object has no Json array in it.

So basically i want to return json from my controller to my javascript file.

Am i missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone explain, what is mean "suburb", may i know what is the suburb of Victoria, Australia?

Answer (score 8):

use this one.

```
public function suburbSearchAction()
    {

        /* Get Suburb text from POST Request */
        $suburbNameQuery = $this->getRequest()->getParam('inputSuburbData');

        /* Retrieve RAM Model at: Webtonic/Ram/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ram.php */
        $model = Mage::getModel('ram/shipping_carrier_ram');
        Mage::register('suburb_query', $suburbNameQuery);
        $model->_getSuburbs();
        $suburbResultArray = Mage::registry('suburb_resultset');

        //$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($suburbResultArray));
$this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($suburbResultArray));
    }
}
```

More Information Ref :: https://raivis.com/returning-json-response-from-magento-controller-action/

Answer (score 2):

You are not specified the header type. So only it take as array. try like this it will work.

```
$suburbResultArray = Mage::registry('suburb_resultset');
$this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($suburbResultArray));
```

Comment: Just use `Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode` instead of `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ramservice/Index/suburbsearch',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {inputSuburbData:inputSuburbData},
            complete: function(responseData) {

                console.log(responseData);

            },
            error:function(response){

                console.log('Response Error');
                console.dir(response);
            }
        });
```

Let me know if you have any issue with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your url in ajax call is wrong I believe. You need to call it like this:

```
url: <?php echo Mage::getUrl('ramservice/index/suburbSearch'),
```

Instead of

```
url: '/ramservice/Index/suburbsearch',
```

ie your ajax call should be this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: <?php echo Mage::getUrl('ramservice/index/suburbSearch'),
        data: {inputSuburbData:inputSuburbData},
        complete: function(responseData) {

            console.log(responseData);

        },
        error:function(response){

            console.log('Response Error');
            console.dir(response);
        }
    });
```

Also make sure your module's frontend name is `ramservice`. If you are not sure how to check this, then update your question with your module's `config.xml` file.

Comment: It works without full url in place (at least on mage 1.9).